# Regex to find phrases

Tags: regex

How can I find two phrases in string like this "`aaaaa   _whitespaces_    phrase1:phrase2`" using only one regex?
I used `s+(.*?):` and `[:](.*)$`, but cant merge them.
Phrases can contain dots quotes and whitespaces.

Example:
Source lines

```
rowN1.           company "concosto developers ltd": contact "John Smith"
rowN2.                      "concosto ltd" company:"John Smith" contact
```

What I wnat to get replacing mathces with ###:

```
rowN1.           ###:###
rowN2.           ###:###
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use this regex:

```
/\w+(?=:|$)/
```

Where `\w+` will match 1 or more rod characters and `(?=:|$)` is a lookahead that means it followed by colon or end of input.

**EDIT:** Based on your edit looks like you can

**search:**

```
( *)[^:]+
```

**repalce by:**

```
$1###
```

Comment: Almost, but quotes and whitespaces brakes it, forexample : aaaaaa                  ssss "sssssss" ssssss:"ddddd ddddd" ddddd

Comment: If you provide some examples in your question with sample input and your expected output I can understand it better to change my answer.

Comment: Close, but row number and spaces are lost

Comment: Does `row1` always start with literal string `row`?

Comment: Also in which language are you trying to do this?

Comment: rowN1. can be a string up to 16 characters length, it can contain any information and always start with latin. C#

Comment: Ok this is the main problem. You're NOT giving important information about the question like C# and `16 characters length` in your question. If you want good answers provide all these details in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry. I just want regex in any dialect working at least with fixed rowN1.

Comment: But you wrote `rownN1` is not a fixed string and it is 16 character string. These things aren't clear like what exactly you want to match from your input and what is stricture of your input.

Comment: Let rowN1. will be stronly "rowN1.". I want to replace phrases in the input around colon with "###". I showed it in example.